# tuple cannot pass into function in pycharm

Tags: python

```py
from turtle import Turtle


class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
        self.goto(position)

paddle = Paddle((350, 0))
```

when run this code in pycharm, return a error like this:
`##KeyError: (350, 0)`

Comment: Missing last two underscores in `def __init__`? The error says there might be more. Please post a [mcve]. Unless this is really the code that raises that error. (I'm on mobile and can't run it right now.)

Comment: Could you post the whole traceback?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed the last two underscores .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that `Turtle.position()` does not take as parameter a tuple, but rather two values: `x` and `y`. If you want to pass in a tuple, you must use the unpack `*` operator like so:

```
def __init__(self, position):
    super().__init__()
    self.shape("square")
    self.color("white")
    self.penup()
    self.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
    self.goto(*position) # here added *
```

what this does is "unpack" the tuple and pass all the contents as different items from
`(x, y)`
to

`x, y`
also add the `__` to your init like so `__init__()`

Also if you need to add parameters to your base class (Turtle), you need to pass them in your `super().__init__(<here>)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass the argument into the `super().__init__()` to initialize the base class `Turtle`, like this `super().__init__(position)`.